# Static text is wx.StaticText is going beyond frame size

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using `wx.Frame`. Inside the frame I am having `wx.Panel`. I am printing some text with `wx.StaticText`. When the text is bigger it is not going into new line in the frame. It is going beyond the frame.

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(800,800))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(800,800), style=wx.BORDER_RAISED)

        text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, dict1[key], pos=(10, 12), style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        font = wx.Font(20, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        text.SetFont(font)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [wrap](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/StaticText.html#StaticText.Wrap) function of StaticText to wrap your string into a given pixel width. This however will not react to resizing of frame. For this you might want to take a look into [AutoWrapStaticText](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.infobar.AutoWrapStaticText.html).

In any case the solution to your question is:

```
 wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(800,800))
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(800,800), style=wx.BORDER_RAISED)

    text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, dict1[key], pos=(10, 12), style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    font = wx.Font(20, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
    text.SetFont(font)
    text.Wrap(width) # This is what I changed.
```